# How do I link_to a route outside of a subdomain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

My routes :

```
class ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper
  def draw routes_name
    instance_eval(File.read(Rails.root.join('config', 'routes', "#{routes_name}.rb")))
  end
```

**routes_a.rb**

```
root :to => 'home#index'
controller :home do
  post 'terms'
```

**routes_b.rb**

```
root :to => 'business/dashboards#show'
```

If I am currently in a subdomain, `community.website.com`, and I create a link_to as so :

```
= link_to 'Here', terms_path
```

It returns as `community.website.com/terms` as opposed to `website.com/terms`.

How do I return `website.com/terms`?

Answer (score 2):

Put this in routes.rb:

```
constraints(:host => /community.website.com/) do
  match '/terms', :to => redirect {|params, request| "http://website.com/terms"}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally I don't answer my own questions, but I thought this would be useful :

```
terms_url(host: request.domain)
```

Where `host: request.domain`  removes subdomain references.